# Read parameter in ActionFilterAttribute that is not present in action's prototype

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am sending a form using Ajax, it has two inputs.
The receiving action only needs to consume one of the passed values.
An `ActionFilterAttribute` needs to consume the other argument.

For this reason, I wrote my action as

```
[AttributeImWriting]
public ContentResult Get(Guid value0) //[...]
```

but in my action filter when I try to do

```
context.ActionArguments["value1"]
```

I get an exception because the argument does not exist.

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'value1' was not present in the dictionary.'

If I change the action's prototype to

```
public ContentResult Get(Guid value0, string value1) //[...]
```

Then I can read `value1` from my filterAttribute.

**So the question is:** In an `ActionFilterAttribute`, how can I read an argument that was sent by a form, but which is not present in the prototype of the action on which the filter is applied?

I also tried using `RouteData.Values` but it didn't work any better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `POST` to send values to controller side , in custom `ActionFilterAttribute` , you can get the parameters from `Form` property :

```
var value1 = context.HttpContext.Request.Form["value1"].ToString();
```

If you are using `Get` to send values to controller side , you can get the parameters from `QueryString` property ,then split and get each item:

```
var querystring = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
```